# Block inserts using for update

Tags: sql, oracle, locking

I am trying to prevent inserts from happening using `select for update` in oracle. For instance suppose in one session (autocommit is off, isolation level = serializable) the Address table contains no rows and I do in SESSION1:

```
SESSION1: select * from Address where addressID = 1 for update
```

Now in SESSION2:

```
SESSION2:insert into Address (addressID, street, city,zip) values (1, 'main','ny','12345'); commit;
```

I would have thought that  is blocked. However, I'm finding that the insert happens. I am able to commit it.  Then in SESSION1 again.

```
  SESSION1: insert into Address (addressID, street, city,zip) values (1, 'main','ny','12345')
```

This gives an integrity constraint error even before a commit. (not as serializable exception as I would have expected).

Why is this happening? I am using oracle 12c.  There are a couple of unexpected results. First why do I get a constraint error in Session1 even before the commit?  Oracle should not see the insert from the other Session.  Secondly, shouldn't the insert in Session1 be blocked due to the "for update" select?  Finally, is there a way to block inserts for  a particular key?

Comment: If your `SELECT FOR UPDATE` doesn't lock a row, it won't have any impact on any session including session 1.  What is the business problem that you are trying to solve?  Wouldn't your inserts use a sequence to generate the `AddressID` eliminating the potential for two sessions to try to insert the same `AddressID` value?  Why do you want to "reserve" a key value in session 1?  I suppose you could insert a mostly empty row and then fill in the data later.  But that may have some unfortunate implications for space utilization.

Comment: Please attach you ORA error for session 1

Comment: @BarakKedem SQL Error: ORA-00001: unique constraint (TEST.SYS_C0010129) violated
00001. 00000 -  "unique constraint (%s.%s) violated"
*Cause:    An UPDATE or INSERT statement attempted to insert a duplicate key.
           For Trusted Oracle configured in DBMS MAC mode, you may see
           this message if a duplicate entry exists at a different level.
*Action:   Either remove the unique restriction or do not insert the key.

Comment: @JustinCave  I am not necessarily using a sequence here.   This is my way of implementing upsert. It has been addressed before, but I was trying to solve it as described here. My question is why this does not work. For example, the approach works fine for Mysql and Oracle.  Also it seems strange that a duplicate key exception is generated when the transaction should not even see the insert from Session 2 (at least until it is committed)

Comment: Implement upset with the MERGE statement.

Comment: I assume you mean something other than Oracle in the sentence "the approach works fine for MySQL and Oracle".  Also, in your question, you state "I am able to commit it." which implies that you are committing the change in session 1.  Are you saying that you are getting a unique constraint error in session 2 when you are not committing in session 1?

Comment: @JustinCave Sorry I meant sql server

Comment: @DavidAldridge  I am aware of that possibility. However, I believe it will be subject to the same problem.   In any case, I am trying to understand why I am seeing the results as described, because I need to use this approach for a more complex example. The upsert was the simplest way to describe the issue.

Comment: @DavidAldridge  Also want to point out that Merge is subject to concurrency issues. See https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/UPSERT#Oracle.2C_MS-SQL.2C_DB2:_SQL_MERGE

Answer (score 2):

See http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2010/10-jan/o65asktom-082389.html about SERIALIZABLE isolation level.

> this degree of isolation comes with a price, and that price is the
>   following possible error:
>
> ```
> ERROR at line 1: ORA-08177: can't serialize access for this transaction
> ```
>
> You'll get this message whenever you try to update a row that has
>   changed since your transaction began. (Note that Oracle tries to do
>   this purely at the row level, but you may receive an ORA-08177 error
>   even when the row you're interested in modifying hasn't been modified.
>   The ORA-08177 may happen due to some other row(s) being modified on
>   the block that contains your row.)

In your case it is not exactly update but the idea is the same. If you query the table, it will not "see" it because it reads from rollback segment.
 But insert is different because it needs to access the real data to ensure consistency.

As for how to work around it - use named locks. They still work although they shouldn't :)

```
Alter session set isolation_level=serializable; 

declare
  v_lockhandle varchar2(128);
  v_result number;
begin
  dbms_lock.allocate_unique('table_name'||'id'
                           ,v_lockhandle);

  v_result := dbms_lock.request(v_lockhandle
                               ,release_on_commit => true
                               ,lockmode => 6 -- exclusive
                               ,timeout => 0);

  dbms_output.put_line('result: '||v_result);
end;
/
```

Comment: It  would make sense to me to get ORA-08177 and I could deal with that. However,  I am getting an integrity constraint error. Nothing in that article explains why that should happen.  SERIALIZABLE should prevent phantom reads which means it should not be able to see inserts from other sessions.    Your thoughts?

Comment: SERIALIZABLE means YOU can not see inserts from other sessions via queries. What Oracle does internally might be something different.

Comment: But an integrity constraint violation within Session1 means that it is seeing the data even before a commit.

Comment: The problem with named locks is that it only works if all inserts use named locks.   So anyone writing code or directly making changes to the database must be aware of that.   That can be a maintenance issue.

Comment: Perhaps you can combine them with pre- row level triggers?